# Variable does not change in python binary game

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am writing a binary game in Python and I don't know why the 2 variables left and right are changing. Here is what I have done so far:

```
def guessNumberBasic(): 
    n=101
    left=0
    right=n-1
    guess=(left+right)//2
    print("Please think of an integer between 1 and 100, but don’t tell me what it is.")
    while True:
        player_ans=input("Is it greater, equal to or less than "+ str(guess) + " (G/E/L)?")
        if player_ans=="E":
                break
        elif player_ans=="G":
                    right=guess+1
        elif player_ans=="L":
                    left=guess+1
    print("I guess you thought of ", guess," Am I right? I know I’m right.")
```

the output:

```
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?G
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?G
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?G
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?G
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?L
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?E
I guess you thought of  50  Am I right? I know I’m right
```

thanks

Comment: you never change the value of guess, you only update right and left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are never changing the value of guess once you set it. You only then change the lsft and right value. Instead you should set guess at the start of each loop

```py
def guessNumberBasic():
    n=101
    left=0
    right=n-1
    print("Please think of an integer between 1 and 100, but don’t tell me what it is.")
    while True:
        guess = (left + right) // 2
        player_ans=input("Is it greater, equal to or less than "+ str(guess) + " (G/E/L)?")
        if player_ans=="E":
                break
        elif player_ans=="G":
                    left=guess+1
        elif player_ans=="L":
                    right=guess+1
    print("I guess you thought of ", guess," Am I right? I know I’m right.")

guessNumberBasic()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Please think of an integer between 1 and 100, but don’t tell me what it is.
Is it greater, equal to or less than 50 (G/E/L)?G
Is it greater, equal to or less than 75 (G/E/L)?L
Is it greater, equal to or less than 63 (G/E/L)?G
Is it greater, equal to or less than 70 (G/E/L)?E
I guess you thought of  70  Am I right? I know I’m right.
```